# Search on value (number) to find text string PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I work with warranty claims and got two sheets with different suppliers, priority and prices for different part numbers for our product.
One sheet with prices/suppliers is used for our repairs in Asia and other sheet is used for the rest of the world (WW)

Sheet 1: PN-List Asia
Sheet 2: PN-List WW

I've managed to make an IF-statement that find the right price, from the right list (PPU).

The formula I've used:

```
    Price Per unit (PPU) =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Regress List'[Continent] ) = "Asia",
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'PN-List Asia'[Price Per Unit] ),
        FILTER ( 'PN-List Asia', 'PN-List Asia'[Prio] = MIN ( 'PN-List Asia'[Prio] ) )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'PN-List WW'[Price Per Unit] ),
        FILTER ( 'PN-List WW', 'PN-List WW'[Prio] = MIN ( 'PN-List WW'[Prio] ) )
    )
)
```

Now I need to get the suppliers name of the product/item, into my matrix in PowerBI.
Suppliers name can be found in the two different sheets (PN-List Asia & PN-List WW) under *supplier name* ('PN-list WW'[supplier name]).

My guess is that I need to use an IF statement to decide if I should search in PN-List Asia or PN-List WW, but I'm not sure how to find the right supplier name with Priority (prio) and/or Price Per Unit (PPU).

[image]

**Answer to @Mik**

Funny enough, I should be able to make an export (to excel) from PowerBI, that looks like this:
[image]

So I can know who to invoice for all the costs. If the supplier wants more information, we will have it in our PowerBI-matrix.

Comment: Is merging both sheets an option? It would be easier to just work with one sheet and passing a filter depending on the selected region.

Comment: Hmm could possibly be a solution. One problem is that one supplier is on both lists and have different priority (first prio in WW but second prio in Asia). How would i need to change my formula to comply with the priority? I could put Asia and WW on the suppliers before i merge them.

Comment: @Fraita can you add a screenshot of your visual?

Comment: why do you use MAX ( 'PN-List Asia'[Price Per Unit] ) and MIN ( 'PN-List Asia'[Prio] ) what is the logic of the expresion? May be you can add 2 dummy tables and a sample of the result?

Comment: I've managed to merge both PN-list's into one now. But it's harder to choose wich price per unit I should take from the PN-list. I've added Continent (Asia & WW) on the suppliers. @JérémieL

Comment: Not sure about the formula, I found it. I want the number 1 prio suppliers to get picked first when choosing price per units. @Mik

Comment: So, you filter your data with Continent in slicer and Job id and item value? And you are trying to get a supplier of item?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your visual, for example, like this? I mean getting of supplier name through measure.

[image]

[image]

used measures

```
Price Per unit (PPU) = 
VAR partNo = SELECTEDVALUE('Claims List (Monthly refilled'[Used Part ])
VAR priority = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('PN-List (static)'[Priority])
        ,TREATAS({partNo},'PN-List (static)'[Part no])
    )
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('PN-List (static)'[Price Per Unit])
        ,TREATAS({partNo},'PN-List (static)'[Part no])
        ,'PN-List (static)'[Priority]=priority
    )


Supplier = 
VAR Usedpart = VALUES('Claims List (Monthly refilled'[Used Part ])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
            SELECTEDVALUE(
                'PN-List (static)'[Supplier name]
                ,IF(
                    ISBLANK(DISTINCTCOUNT('PN-List (static)'[Supplier name]))
                    ,BLANK()
                    ,"- " & DISTINCTCOUNT('PN-List (static)'[Supplier name]) & " Suppliers")
            )
        ,TREATAS(Usedpart,'PN-List (static)'[Part no])
    )
```

Comment: Couldn't make it with the filter and the end product seems to be difficult to fix.

I've made a "dummy table" with (almost) all the formulas that I've managed to do in Excel. Google Sheets doesn't have "xlookup", so I couldn't involve the priority. 

Here is a link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_nl2_Dgam7JDdyzX-urrO2AEXuCzhQkB1nogTLn2eA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As I understood a blue is an input and orange is what you want to get in PBI, right? I don't see how to link supplier and Job ID. And the whole data model remains unlinked. In the supplier table you don't have unique values. It's not possible to establish relation. As I see we can create a calculted column to link job ID and supplier via part in the Claims List or make a table with Supplier and partNo only (the best solution as for me) this will alow to link the data model or (not the best way - create 2 columns for prices instead of one).

Comment: In a current model any result will be doubtful.

Comment: yeah it's kind a messy. That's why I'm trying to find a solution. Job ID connects labour cost (that are sent monthly) and used part connects price/cost for the parts + who supplied these parts.

Comment: I altered the answer, so, please check. Note that slisers are not selected, that is why you get number of supplers instead of name. If you will use the slicer then you will see name.

Comment: I've made an edit in my post, not sure how to answer you with a picture here in comments @Mik. 
It's not an optimal situation I'm in, I get new directives every day of what "this PowerBI-tool" should be able to do. Many sheets and functions makes it hard to give a complete picture of how "I" want it.